# Why do I get EnvironmentNotWritableError while installing eli5

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I'm new to Python (1 month into Python). Trying to install eli5 to Python. I used

```
conda install -c conda-forge eli5
```

Got error message

> EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
>     environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

Appreciate assistance, thanks.

Per https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/eli5, I have tried

1. `conda install -c conda-forge eli5`
2. `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 eli5`
3. `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 eli5`

All returned same message.

Answer (score 6):

**Windows** : Open a Anaconda Power shell promt (using Windows search) **as administrator** and type in `conda install -c conda-forge eli5`, if the command freezes after a while, press **Ctrl + C** and it will continue with collecting package metadata.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new environment and activate it, and then try installing the package from that environment using the below code

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

Comment: My original problem was that I needed administrator privileges to install packages in a privileged directory, when using the base environment. But, creating my own environment ensured that the packages were being installed in a non-privileged directory where I have write permission. This answer solved my problem.

Comment: @Ishrak Same problem here, mine solved too.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very error when updating conda:

```
conda update conda
```

To run the Anaconda Power shell prompt **as administrator** you need to right click the menu item first.

It allowed the update to write to the location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

Answer (score 1):

For me the trick was: **Right click on Anaconda Navigator -> run as Administrator**. Now any prompt/terminal started from the navigator (e.g. by clicking on the play button and start a terminal) runs with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` command:

```
sudo conda install <package>
```